# Resend iMessage

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

Is there a quick method to resend an iMessage? The particular, I send an iMessage (stop and bus number) to the transit service. In cold weather, the multi-step copy, paste re-send is cumbersome. The touch screen does not like -20 weather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. In iOS 7, the resend/forward button (Select a message, tap More…, bottom right, enter contact) is a lot more work.

However, you can set up a shortcut in Settings > General > Keyboard which should make things much faster.

[image]

In the screenshot I have qqq doing that so all you have to do is type q three times and hit send.

If it doesn't have to be an iMessage, there are apps like [Fast Msg](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fast-msg-group-text-message/id590391496?mt=8) that should be able to store a contact and message to send with a single tap.

Comment: Thanks. A good trick. Perhaps a "resend message" function will present itself in a future version.